# Spring annotation to create a jexl2.Expression

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jexl

I’m trying to understand a piece of Spring code that I need to adapt.
 
 I have:

```
<bean id="…" class="…">
  <property name="expr"
           value="teams.contains(member.team) and not empty(member.projects)" />
</bean>
```

The corresponding class has a field

```
private Expression expr;
```

of type

```
org.apache.commons.jexl2.Expression
```

Now I am trying to find the appropriate Spring annotation to get rid of the XML file. But I cannot even understand *how* a simple String property can be injected as a jexl2.Expression object. How does this work?

Comment: It seems, that an [Expression is created](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/javadocs/apidocs-2.1/org/apache/commons/jexl2/package-summary.html#example) with `JexlEngine.createExpression("the jexl expression...")`. So now the question may be: how does Spring know that it should call `bean.setExpr(aJexlEngine.createExpression(theValue))` instead of `bean.setExpr(theValue)`; and where does aJexlEngine come from?

Answer (score 0):

A friend found the answer:

There was another XML file with this:

```
<bean id="bean_for_ExprConverter" class="package.of.custom.ExpressionConverter">
  <constructor-arg ref="bean_for_JexlEngine"/>
</bean>
```

and also, in the project’s properties:

```
application.spring.converters = #{{\
  @'bean_for_ExprConverter'\
}}
```

Thus, as long as the converter bean is defined, it should be enough to simply inject the expression string with the `@Value` annotation.